# Dynamic Process communication in Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-sockets

I am building a socket server that is creating new MP Process for each client. Clients may need to exchange data between themselves, like chat messages. How should I set up the communication so that it would work dynamically? The problem is, that MP Queues are not picklable, so after creating new Process I have no way to share new Queue with already existing ones. I could use external solutions like RabbitMQ but if possible I'd like to keep it simple.

Also, I know that I could share the queue with Manager object, but I believe that if one client would retrieve the objects from it, the others would not receive them.

Edit: I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve this dynamic kind of communication without 3rd party tools.

Comment: You explained two solutions already. You also seem to be aware of the pro and cons of them. So I'm wondering what you are expecting from us. An other solution with other pros and cons?

Comment: I'd like to know if there is a way to set up a communication dynamically without 3rd party solutions. The second solution with Manager is not what I am looking for since I have no way to dynamically share the queues between processes after they are created.

Comment: You would basically have to reimplement the feature of AMQP you would be using in your idea #1, by using multiple queues. IMHO AMQP is a good solution especially because the architecture can be scaled horizontally with it.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed